# Connect-Mongo and Express-session cannot work well

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, express

I have tried to connect my MongoDB remotely, and did CURD successfully using MongoClient object.

[image]

However, when I wanted to add session support on my Node.js service with packages **connect-mongo** and **express-session**, it always showed me the following error
***"MongoError: database name must be a string"***.

Some say it's needed to use package **mongoose** to connect on the MongoDB, but it, however, did not work either.
The same code is workable on packages **mysql** and **connect-mysql** when connecting to MySQL server remotely and locally.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use moongose in Production and that's how we handle the database connection, using the db Properties as env variables.

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:${dbPort}/${dbName}`,
{user: dbUser, pass: dbPassword, auth: {authdb: 'admin'}, useNewUrlParser: true})
```